# cambio de login con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un cambio de login segun una lista de usuario.
En la tabla de usuario, tengo el siguiente botón

```
$btnLogin = '<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick="fntCambiarCliente('.$arrData[$i]['idpersona'].')" title="Login cliente"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button>';
```

que al hacer click, me salta al js

```
function fntCambiarCliente(idpersona){
    var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Clientes/logCliente/';
    let strData = "idpersona="+idpersona;
    request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
    request.send(strData);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            
        }
    }
}
```

En el modelo tengo el siguiente:

```
public function logCliente(){
        //dep($_POST);
        $strUsuario = $_POST['idpersona'];
        $requestUser = $this->model->loginCliente($strUsuario);
        if(empty($requestUser)){
            $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'Datos de login incorrectos' ); 
        }else{
            $arrData = $requestUser;
            if($arrData['status'] == 1){
                $_SESSION['idUser'] = $arrData['idpersona'];
                $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                $arrData = $this->model->sessionLogin($_SESSION['idUser']);
                sessionUser($_SESSION['idUser']);                           
                $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'ok');
            }else{
                $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'Usuario inactivo.');
            }
        }
        
        echo json_encode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        die();
    }
```

y basicamente en el control tengo un select idpersona from persona where idpersona = '$idpersona'

sin embargo, me da el error de Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 que no se donde mirar.

gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: En tu php... ¿Devuelves realmente un json? ¿Tienes el header `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=XXXXX');`?

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder al $_POST['idpersona'], primero debes enviar bien el JSON desde el JS, cambiando tu linea asi:

```
function fntCambiarCliente(idpersona){
var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Clientes/logCliente/';
// En lugar de esto
let strData = "idpersona="+idpersona;
// Envia esto
let strData = {
   idpersona: idpersona
}
request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
request.send(strData);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
        let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        
    }
}
```

}

Esto debe solucionar tu problema y podrás acceder al dato por POST correctamente.